# React Native WebView getting response from different source

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am loading a React Native's `WebView` component like so:

```
<WebView 
  source={{uri: 'http://www.example-one.com'}}
  onMessage = {(event) => console.log(event.nativeEvent.data)}
/>
```

And inside my `www.example-one.com` I add this javascript code

```
window.postMessage('It works!!');
```

This works great and I am able to the message from `www.example-one.com` in my React Native's console.

However, when I load the same `WebView` with same `source` and redirect the user to different `source` say `www.example-two.com` from inside `wwww.example-one.com` and add the javascript code inside `www.example-two.com` i.e.

```
window.postMessage('It works from example two!!');
```

then I don't see that message inside React Native's console.

Is there any work around to make this work?

Comment: I am also getting this need data from a different origin. Can anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Raised issue in react-native-webview https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/issues/427